# How do I pass a command containing "-c" to a remote machine using SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, arguments

I'm using SSH to pass a command to a remote machine. The command is to update my Plex Media Server, so in long form it is:

```
ssh myhost $PATHTOPLEXSCANNER -c 3 -s
```

The "-c 3 -s" are arguments that the Plex Media Scanner needs. I can't leave the -c out.

When I run this in a script, I get an error: "Unknown cipher type '3'". I know this is because SSH is interpreting the -c part of the argument as a cipher specification.

If I type this command in at the prompt, it runs fine.
If I run the exact same command in a script, I receive the cipher error.
How can I pass the "-c 3 -s" arguments to the remote machine?

The full command is:

```
ssh myhost '/Applications/Plex\ Media\ Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Plex\ Media\ Scanner' -c 3 -s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrapped it with double quote.

`ssh myhost "$PATHTOPLEXSCANNER -c 3 -s"`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but now I get a different error:

bash: -c: command not found

Comment: what is the value of `$PATHTOPLEXSCANNER`

Comment: It's `'/Applications/Plex\ Media\ Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Plex\ Media\ Scanner'`

Comment: You mention a difference between running this from the command line and in a script. Are you sure the variable is set in the script? The error sounds like your command is equivalent to `ssh myhost "-c 3 -s"`, consistent with `PATHTOPLEXSCANNER` being unset.

Comment: Good catch. I set `PATHTOPLEXSCANNER` on login, not in the script. When I redefined it in the script itself, everything worked well! Thanks so much!